# MYSQL TotalValue when another column has a set value

Tags: mysql, sum

I have a database and I am trying to get a list of names along side the total value for items borrowed.

Currently all of the data I need can be viewed in the query below.

```
SELECT *
FROM Borrower b
JOIN Loan l ON b.BorId = l.BorId
JOIN BookCopy bc ON l.BcId = bc.BcId
JOIN BookTitle bt ON bc.BtId = bt.BtId
```

At the end of the day I want b.BorName in a column and the sum of bt.Value for each of the borrowers in another column.

The statement above shows multiple rows for each BorName as each person has multiple items borrowed, but I want to reduce this down to one row per Borrower with the Sum of all the relating bt.value fields in another column.

I have tried to select below

```
SELECT b.BorName, SUM(DISTINCT bt.Value) as Total
FROM Borrower b
JOIN Loan l ON b.BorId = l.BorId
JOIN BookCopy bc ON l.BcId = bc.BcId
JOIN BookTitle bt ON bc.BtId = bt.BtId
```

But this simply returns a single row for the first Borrower in the query with their Total Value.

I have reached the limit of my current MYSQL knowledge and have tried looking further into GROUP BY e.g. SUM and sub queries but cant work out what I am meant to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT b.BorName, SUM(bt.Value) AS 'Total'
FROM Borrower b
JOIN Loan l ON b.BorId = l.BorId
JOIN BookCopy bc ON l.BcId = bc.BcId
JOIN BookTitle bt ON bc.BtId = bt.BtId
GROUP BY b.BorName
```

Comment: What if I then wanted to limit this to where the 'Total' value was > 10?
I have tried a simple WHERE both before and after the GROUP BY referencing either Total or SUM(bt.Value) but neither work.

Comment: For anyone else this link will help http://codespatter.com/2008/07/22/conditions-on-count-or-sum-in-mysql/
The word you are looking for is HAVING

Comment: @mr.user1065741 Yes, you need to use `HAVING`